# how to use lapply to add the value of each number in a vector to a list of DFs

Tags: r

I have a list in which each element is a DF of two columns and there are n total DFs (length of the list). I also have a numeric vector of length n. I want to add (sum) each numeric value in the vector to each DF in the list.
For example,

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = runif(3))
df2 <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = runif(3))
dfs <- dfs <- list(df1, df2)
a <- c(1,2)
print(dfs)

[[1]]
      x         y
 1 0.8272478 0.2574596
 2 0.6211760 0.9493301
 3 0.7034334 0.9994961

[[2]]
      x         y
1 0.3088512 0.7153767
2 0.2060098 0.8956978
3 0.5299310 0.1292302
```

I want the result to be

```
 [[1]]
      x         y
 1 1.8272478 1.2574596
 2 1.6211760 1.9493301
 3 1.7034334 1.9994961

[[2]]
      x         y
1 2.3088512 2.7153767
2 2.2060098 2.8956978
3 2.5299310 2.1292302
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to sum the corresponding elements of 'dfs' with the elements of 'a'

```
Map(`+`, dfs, a)
#[[1]]
#        x        y
#1 1.827248 1.257460
#2 1.621176 1.949330
#3 1.703433 1.999496

#[[2]]
#        x        y
#1 2.308851 2.715377
#2 2.206010 2.895698
#3 2.529931 2.129230
```

Comment: Thank you, for the fast response

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it only using lapply, as the title of the question, you need to be able to keep track of what position you are on. This calls for a global counter that persists between function calls.

```
curIndex <- 1
```

Then, we need a function that will add the correct element to the given data.frame, and increment the counter.

```
addNextElement <- function(x) {
  nextElement <- a[curIndex]
  curIndex <<- curIndex + 1
  return(as.data.frame(lapply(x, `+`, nextElement)))
}
```

Then just apply the above function to each df.

```
> lapply(dfs, addNextElement)
#[[1]]
#         x        y
#1 1.391478 1.174208
#2 1.753578 1.222098
#3 1.973113 1.569923
# 
#[[2]]
#         x        y
#1 2.454878 2.135680
#2 2.749754 2.132524
#3 2.269514 2.241654
```